# Indexing pages with #! in URL

Tags: ajax, parameters, seo, fragment

In google webmaster tools account under url parameters there is a _escaped_fragment_ parameter. Since google states that it doesn't crawl these urls should i tell it not to crawl these urls in this section?

Also I would like that google crawls my urls that have #! in them since this is what sorts out the pictures in my gallery.

Google also states to add this: `<meta name="fragment" content="!">` to the pages that contain these urls. Is this proper procedure? I have noticed that Google isn't crawling these types of urls. Will it crawl it now that I have added this?

Answer (score -1):

Google will actually crawl the `_escaped_fragment_` version of the URLs, because fragments only exist on client side; that's the main reason the [AJAX Crawling Scheme](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more) was created.
If you limit the crawler's access to those URLs, your site will have a very rough time in search results, so I would recommend letting the crawler access it (i.e. don't set any special handling for them).

The meta tag you mention will actually tell Google to **not** rewrite the URLs; that's not what you want if you have hashbangs (#!) in the URL, so don't add the meta tag.

> In order to make pages without hash fragments crawlable, you include a special meta tag in the head of the HTML of your page. The meta tag takes the following: `<meta name="fragment" content="!">`

Comment: Your answer is a bit confusing. So under webmaster tools I should let google crawl every url with this parameter? And should I add the meta tag in my header?

Comment: Updated the answer to make it more specific.

Comment: Due to fact that i have 32000 urls monitored in google webmaster tools. I will let googlebot crawl the urls. However I am also getting these types of crawl errors : https://example.com/announcements/jacobgriffit?_escaped_fragment_= with empty values. Should I remove/block these urls in my robots.txt? Or should i create a htaccess redirect when empty escape_fragement parameters are passed?